# Differences Between WP_Query() and get_posts() for Querying Posts?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, performance

What are the differences between using [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)? Which is better to use in what case and why?

Comment: What @John P Bloch said.

Comment: Here is similar question with very good answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `get_posts()` actually instantiates a new `WP_Query` object, so if you're comfortable using `WP_Query` directly, don't even bother with `get_posts()`; `get_posts` will only return the results from the database, whereas `WP_Query` gives you the whole functionality of the class.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what John P Bloch says, you can modify the default WP_Query object (instead of creating an new instance) before it runs with it's class methods and an action hook, reducing the db calls you make.