# When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query, get-posts

It seems like half the tutorials in the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) and around the blogosphere use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and half use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

They all do similar things, so when should I use one over the others?

Comment: Check also this [longer analysis](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226960/why-query-posts-isnt-marked-as-deprecated/248955#248955)

Answer (score 745, accepted):

- [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) is overly simplistic and a problematic way to modify the main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination). Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like making use of the [`pre_get_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) hook, for this purpose. TL;DR **don't use query_posts() ever**.
- [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) is very similar in usage and accepts the same arguments (with some nuances, like different defaults), but returns an array of posts, doesn't modify global variables and is safe to use anywhere.
- [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) is the class that powers both behind the scenes, but you can also create and work with your own instance of it. A bit more complex, fewer restrictions, also safe to use anywhere.

[image]

Comment: (1) "and is safe to use anywhere" --> but do not use this for the MAIN loop. (2) remember to use global $query_string; before the line that has query_posts();

Comment: @scribu then again 'get_posts' will work although not advised: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16545

Comment: I believe that `query_posts` is also less efficient in that it will run additional queries, when if you use only `WP_Query` for your main loop, it will only run the query you choose in WP_Query.

Comment: @jjeaton `query_posts()` is tiny wrapper function for `WP_Query`, the only extra thing it does (as per flowchart) is overwriting global `$wp_query`

Comment: @Rarst I was referring to [this section in the Codex for query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Additional_SQL_Queries) however, I may be mistaken regarding the effect on performance. Unless using WP_Query in your template file will also have the same result (i.e. throwing away your query, and re-executing)

Comment: @jjeaton Replacing `query_posts()` with `WP_Query` will make no difference in performance, original page's query will still run because that is part of core load. Those queries will run even if your template file has no loop at all.

Comment: Can't get rid off the feeling that this the most genious and upvoted post on WPSE. Should be in Codex as well.

Comment: Ok, after looking at it for more than quite a time, I think `query_posts()` is missing a static var that get's set to true after the first use and - if used twice - should trigger `_doing_it_wrong();`. Guess I'm going to bug the wp-hacker or trac guys about this.

Comment: @kaiser well... using `query_posts()` twice is about as bad as once, doesn't matter much as for me. :) btw Andrew Nacin is going to do presentation on queries and he said he might propose some improvements to the flowchart, so version two might be coming some time in the future.

Comment: I'll just add my clearest description of the "performance of query_posts()" issue: Using query_posts() or WP_Query within a template file will have the same performnace cost: the query you just performed. The issue discussed in the codex article is that if you actually want to replace the query you should do so by filtering the original query_posts() with the 'parse_query' filter. That way you only have the one, original, desirable query, rather than doing a second query to awkwardly replace it. query_posts() is NEVER THE WAY!! NEVER!

Comment: This makes no mention of the 'request' filter, which is a great way to modify the main query. The advantage over query_posts is that function wipes out the original query and generates a new one - same as if you used WP_Query. By using the request filter, your modifying the original query before its ever sent. I think thats what @JeremyClarke is getting at above.

Comment: There's a freaking awesome explanation of query_posts written by John James Jacoby on the developer.wordpress.com blog that blows all of these answers out of the water. The main point: `query_posts` doesn't *modify* the main loop at all, it *replaces* it *after* it has already run. The best way to modify the main loop is through a `pre_get_posts` filter.

http://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/

Comment: @Dan you are confusing technical implementation and purpose. `query_posts()` does replace main loop object, but the purpose of it is to modify main loop. Also I am warmly fond of loop filters, but that wasn't what question asked. There is follow up question from other person on that topic.

Comment: The question was "When should you use... query_posts()" and according to the logic presented by that blog post and the comments above, the answer is likely never.

Comment: so, if its so bad, why does `query_posts` exist?

Comment: @Manny Fleurmond conceptually `query_posts()` is an attempt to dumb down main loop concepts to the level of theme template tag (ease of which is one of the strong points for WP popularity). The task simply turned out to be too much for template tag to possibly accomplish. Core developers did voice possibility of it getting deprecated but I don't think there was decision about that yet.

Comment: You actually can't "use anywhere" the WP_Query(), i just tried and it still croaks at $thequery->have_posts(), infinite recursion, see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34270

Comment: @NoBugs the loop in that question is wrong and there is answer explaining why.

Comment: Agghh thanks for this. Finally, something makes sense. Seriously, WordPress and their lousy documentation. I don't know how such convoluted software and bad coding standards became so popular.

Comment: Found this speed test between wp_query and get_posts http://www.wpclocked.com/

Comment: I would trust such test... exactly none. :) The function is a _very_ thin wrapper, any difference will be coming from slight difference in arguments and/or hooks.

Comment: No need for emotions, query_posts() is a function with side effects: setting a global. WordPress is staggerd with functions with side effects. This is not a performance issue but a quality of code issue. Look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/ and see what query_posts does. Use WP_Query unless you want to mess up global variables.

Answer (score 93):

`query_posts` - You should never ever use `query_posts`. Apart from what @Rarst has said, the really big issue with `query_posts` is, it breaks the main query object ( stored in `$wp_query` ). A lot of plugins and custom code relies on the main query object, so breaking the main query object means that you are breaking the functionalities of plugins and custom code. Just one such function is the all important pagination function, so if you break the main query, you break pagination.

To prove how bad `query_posts` is, on any template, do the following and compare the results

```
var_dump( $wp_query );
query_posts( '&posts_per_page=-1' );
var_dump( $wp_query );
```

`get_posts` and `WP_Query` are the correct way to construct **secondary** queries ( *like related posts, sliders, featured content <strike>and content on static front pages</strike>* ) with. It should be noted, you should not use any of the two in favor of the main query on the home page, single page or any type of archive page as it will break page functionality. If you need to modify the main query, use `pre_get_posts` to do so, and not a custom query. (***UPDATE:*** For static front pages and true pages, see [Using pre_get_posts on true pages and static front pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/214895/31545)*)

In essence, `WP_Query` is used by the main query and is also used by `get_posts`, but although `get_posts()` uses `WP_Query`, there are a few differences

- `get_posts` are faster than `WP_Query`. The margin depends on the amount of total posts of the site. The reason for this is, `get_posts` passes `'no_found_rows' => true` by default to `WP_Query` which skips/legally breaks pagination. With `'no_found_rows' => true`, `WP_Query` gets the amount of posts queried, then bails out, where by default, it further search for all posts matching the query in order to calculate pagination.

  For this reason, `get_posts()` should be used for non paginated queries only. Paginating `get_posts` is really one big mess. `WP_Query` should be used for all paginated queries
- `get_posts()` aren't influenced by the `posts_*` filters where `WP_Query` gets influenced by these filters. The reason is that `get_posts`, by default, passes `'suppress_filters' => true` to `WP_Query`
- `get_posts` has a couple of extra parameters like `include`, `exclude`, `numberposts` and `category`. These parameters do get changed into valid parameters for `WP_Query` before being passed to `WP_Query`. `include`  gets changed into `post__in`, `exclude` into `post__not_in`, `category` into `cat` and `numberposts` into `posts_per_page`. Just a note, **all** of the parameters that can be passed to `WP_Query` works with `get_posts`, you **can** ignore and not use the default parameters of `get_posts`
- `get_posts` returns just the `$posts` property of `WP_Query` while `WP_Query` returns the complete object. This object is quite useful when it comes to conditionals, pagination and other useful info that can be used inside the loop.
- `get_posts` doesn't use the loop, but a `foreach` loop to display posts. Also, no template tags are available by default. `setup_postdata( $post )` has to be used to make the template tags available. `WP_Query` uses the loop and template tags are available by default
- `get_posts` passes `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1` to `WP_Query`, so `get_posts` by default ignores sticky posts

Based on the above, whether to use `get_posts` or `WP_Query` is up to you and what do you actually need from the query. The above should guide you in your choice

Comment: I wish I could favorite answers. This explains so much.

Comment: Great Explanation!

"get_posts() should be used for non paginated queries only. Paginating get_posts is really one big mess. WP_Query should be used for all paginated queries" Is basically all someone needs to know imo.

Comment: @pieter-goosen, do you know if this same is true for WP User Query versus get_users? Referring to the performance part.

Answer (score 35):

The basic difference is that `query_posts()` is really only for modifying the current Loop. Once you're done it's necessary to reset the loop and send it on its merry way. This method is also a little easier to understand, simply because your "query" is basically a URL string that you pass to the function, like so:

```
query_posts('meta_key=color&meta_value=blue');
```

On the other hand, `WP_Query` is more of a general purpose tool, and is more like directly writing MySQL queries than `query_posts()` is. You can also use it anywhere (not just in the Loop) and it doesn't interfere with any currently running post queries.

I tend to use `WP_Query` more often, as it happens. Really, it's going to come down to your specific case.

Answer (score 17):

There is simply no need to use `query_posts()`. All it does is instantiates a new WP_Query object and reassigns that new object to `global wp_query`.

For reference, the following is that actual `query_posts()` function.

```
 function query_posts($query) {
        $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = new WP_Query();
        return $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query($query);
    }
```

Instantiate your own WP_Query object if you want to create an in depth custom query script. Or use `get_posts()` if all you need to do is some light manipulation here and there.

In either case, I highly recommend doing yourself a favor and going to `wp_includes/query.php` and perusing the `WP_Query` class.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that you use  `wp_reset_query()` after using `query_posts()` because it will affect other query result also.

Answer (score 12):

If I recall reading right, essentially "the loop" is doing `WP_Query` in the core files, but in an easier to understand way.

Answer (score 9):

- [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts): might be used in one and only case if you need to modify main query . It sets a lot of global variables;
- [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts): it is  very similar in mechanics and accepts same arguments, but returns array of posts
- [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query):  you can  create and work with own object of it. Bit more complex, less restrictions, it is  safe to use anywhere.